# How to implement a custom op that uses intermediate data from the forward pass to compute its gradient faster in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, customization, derivative

I am trying to implement a custom op in TensorFlow that represents a computationally heavy transfer function computed in C++ using Eigen on GPU. I would like to accelerate the computation of the gradient (also in C++ for speed) of the op by re-using some of the intermediate values obtained while computing its output.

In the source code of [tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_ops_gradients.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_ops_gradients.h) we see that many functions already do that to some extent by re-using the output of the op to compute its derivative. Here is the example of the sigmoid:

```
template <typename T>
struct scalar_sigmoid_gradient_op {
  EIGEN_EMPTY_STRUCT_CTOR(scalar_sigmoid_gradient_op)
  EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE const T
  operator()(const T& output, const T& output_gradient) const {
    return output_gradient * output * (T(1) - output);
  }
```

However, I don't see how I can access something else than just the output, for example some other values I stored during the forward pass, to accelerate the computation of my derivative.

I've thought about adding a second output to my op, with all the data required for the derivative, and use it for the computation of the gradient of the actual output, but I've not managed to make it work yet. I'm not sure if it could work in principle.

Another approach I imagined is to manually modify the full graph (forward and backprop) to shortcut an output from the op directly towards its derivative block. I'm not sure how to do it.

Otherwise, there may be a data storage scheme I'm not aware of and that would allow me to store data in the forward pass of an op and retrieve it during gradient computation.

Thank you for your attention, I would greatly appreciate any ideas.
D

Comment: "I've thought about adding a second output to my op, with all the data required for the derivative, and use it for the computation of the gradient of the actual output, but I've not managed to make it work yet." That's what I'd try and it should work.

Comment: here's an example of rewiring the graph using graph editor -- https://github.com/yaroslavvb/notebooks/blob/master/simple_rewiring.ipynb